# How can I fix "EMPTYUNREACHABLE" on deploying a test replset on my mac?

Tags: mongodb, localhost, replication

I'm trying to deploy a development/test replication set on my macbook pro using this document.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

I started 3 instances of mongod, each on port 10001, 10002, 10003
I used the configuration file to start mongod. The configuration file below:

```
rs0:

dbpath = /Users/Thomas/mongodb/data/rs0/
port = 10000
logpath = /Users/Thomas/mongodb/log/rs0.log
logappend = true
replSet = rs0

rs1:

dbpath = /Users/Thomas/mongodb/data/rs1/
port = 10001
logpath = /Users/Thomas/mongodb/log/rs1.log
logappend = true
replSet = rs0

rs2:

dbpath = /Users/Thomas/mongodb/data/rs2/
port = 10002
logpath = /Users/Thomas/mongodb/log/rs2.log
logappend = true
replSet = rs0
```

And using the following command to start:

```
mongod -f config/rs0.conf
mongod -f config/rs1.conf
mongod -f config/rs2.conf
```

then I connect to it using mongo: mongo localhost:10001, but when I use rs.initiate() command to initialize the repl set, it failed.

```
> rs.initiate()
{
"startupStatus" : 4,
"info" : "rs0",
"errmsg" : "all members and seeds must be reachable to initiate set",
"ok" : 0
}
```

and check by rs.status()

```
> rs.status()
{
"startupStatus" : 4,
"errmsg" : "can't currently get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYUNREACHABLE)",
"ok" : 0
}
```

And the log shows it's a EMPTYUNREACHABLE error. how could solve it?

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****

Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=568 port=10000              dbpath=/Users/Thomas/mongodb/data/rs0/ 64-bit host=bogon
Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [initandlisten]
Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.0, pdfile version 4.5
Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [initandlisten] git version: f5e83eae9cfbec7fb7a071321928f00d1b0c5207
Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-1.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [initandlisten] options: { config: "config/rs0.conf", dbpath: "/Users/Thomas/mongodb/data/rs0/", logappend: "true", logpath: "/Users/Thomas/mongodb/log/rs0.log", port: 10000, replSet: "rs0", rest: "true" }
Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [initandlisten] journal dir=/Users/Thomas/mongodb/data/rs0/journal
Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 11000
Mon Oct 15 22:02:31 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 10000
Mon Oct 15 22:02:37 [rsStart] trying to contact bogon:10000
Mon Oct 15 22:02:43 [rsStart] couldn't connect to bogon:10000: couldn't connect to server bogon:10000
Mon Oct 15 22:02:49 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (yet)
Mon Oct 15 22:03:05 [rsStart] trying to contact bogon:10000
Mon Oct 15 22:03:11 [rsStart] couldn't connect to bogon:10000: couldn't connect to server bogon:10000
Mon Oct 15 22:03:17 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (yet)
Mon Oct 15 22:03:33 [rsStart] trying to contact bogon:10000
Mon Oct 15 22:03:39 [rsStart] couldn't connect to bogon:10000: couldn't connect to server   bogon:10000
Mon Oct 15 22:03:45 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (yet)
Mon Oct 15 22:04:01 [rsStart] trying to contact bogon:10000
Mon Oct 15 22:04:07 [rsStart] couldn't connect to bogon:10000: couldn't connect to server bogon:10000
Mon Oct 15 22:04:13 [rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (yet)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try setting bind_ip to 127.0.0.1 or add an entry for `bogon' to your /etc/hosts?

mongodb appears to be getting the hostname() for the local system but it’s not resolvable.

Comment: OH, thank you very much, I have tried the /etc/hosts way and the problem was solved. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact issue today. I was able to start mongodb but not the replica sets. I had to delete the following line from the mongod.conf file

'bind_ip: "127.0.0.1"'

I also figured out that the mongod.conf files for mongodb and replica sets were different and stored at different locations, maybe because I brew installed the latest version of mongodb?. I found my replica set config file at "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf".

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I believe you hit this bug in 2.2.0:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7367

It is now fixed and scheduled for release in 2.2.1 - the fixes for 2.2.0 basically involve making sure that you use resolvable and reachable addresses for your sets because 2.2.0 tries to reach even local instances over the network.